# Runtime HTML modifying in Android

Tags: android, html

I am new in Android development and learning about it in off-time. I was making a "Web Feed Analyzer" like app where I am fetching a feed from a website and displaying its contains in a Web-view like this : 
`WebView w = new WebView(this); 
w.loadData(strData,"text/html","utf-8");`

It is working fine.
BUT what I want to do is to **MODIFY the HTML data stored in the strData variable and STRIP some elements** from it before calling loadData.

I am considering parsing the HTML some how, but I dont know how to do it properly and I prefer simple approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: consider jsoup for parsing html. otherwise you could also add some javascript to act on the html

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I said in my post I am just a beginner in Android development so I have no idea about jsoup (though I am hearing about it a lot in stack-overflow). I could not understand how java script will help in this situation. Could you please elaborate kindly?

Comment: strip some elements is a bit vague, but if it is about hiding some parts, it can probably be done in javascript

Comment: Stripping elements means say the html is consisting with hyperlink, image and a paragraph. I just want the paragraph content. Silly me, I also tried to use XMLPullParser to parse the html and it given like a million error! LOL.

Answer (score 0):

After realizing that Jsoup is beyond my capabilities I took the most DIRTY and SLOPPY approach for solving my own problem. The problem was to PARSE html string and Stripping elements from it. Well I could not actually parsed anything but able to extract specific parts from the html through good old **String handling**.

Here is the Sample html :

```
<a href="http://yts.re/movie/Night_on_Earth_1991"><img style="float:left" src="http://static.yts.re/attachments/Night_on_Earth_1991/poster_med.jpg" alt="Night on Earth (1991) - YIFY-Torrents" /></a><br /> <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102536/">http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102536/</a><br /> IMDB Rating: 7.8/10<br /> Genre: Comedy | Drama<br /> Quality: 720p<br /> Size: 876.69 MB<br /> Run Time: 2hr 7 min<br /> <p>A collection of five stories involving cab drivers in five different cities. Los Angeles - A talent agent for the movies discovers her cab driver would be perfect to cast, but the cabbie is reluctant to give up her solid cab driver's career. New York - An immigrant cab driver is continually lost in a city and culture he doesn't understand. Paris - A blind girl takes a ride with a cab driver from the Ivory Coast and they talk about life and blindness. Rome - A gregarious cabbie picks up an ailing man and virtually talks him to death. Helsinki - an industrial worker gets laid off and he and his compatriots discuss the bleakness and unfairness of love and life and death.</p>
```

To "Parse" this string I have used the following code :

```
private void breakdown(String html) {
    //Extracting YTSLink
    int ls = html.indexOf("href=") + 6;
    int le = html.indexOf(">") - 1;
    String ytsLink = html.substring(ls,le);

    //Extraction ImagePath
    int is = html.indexOf("src=") + 5;
    int ie = html.indexOf("alt=") - 2;
    String imgPath = html.substring(is,ie);

    //Extracting IMDBLink
    ls = html.lastIndexOf("href=") + 6;
    le = html.indexOf(">",ls) - 1;
    String imdbLink = html.substring(ls,le);

    //Extracting PlotSummary
    int ps = html.indexOf("<p>") + 3;
    int pe = html.indexOf("</p>");
    String summary = html.substring(ps,pe);

    //Extracting IMDBRatings and Other Attributes
    int s = html.indexOf("IMDB Rating:");
    int l = html.indexOf("<br />",s);
    String imdbRating = html.substring(s,l);

    s = html.indexOf("Genre:");
    l = html.indexOf("<br />",s);
    String genre = html.substring(s,l);

    s = html.indexOf("Quality:");
    l = html.indexOf("<br />",s);
    String quality = html.substring(s,l);

    s = html.indexOf("Size:");
    l = html.indexOf("<br />",s);
    String fileSize = html.substring(s,l);

    s = html.indexOf("Run Time:");
    l = html.indexOf("<br />",s);
    String runTime = html.substring(s,l);
}
```

The html was formatted in a pre-determined way. All I did is extract the info from it part by part by calculating their positions. Obviously it is a sloppy solution. I am still looking for a better approach.